# Compilter error C2733 when using Quicktime SDK inside Visual Studio C++ MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, quicktime

I am developing an VC++ MFC application using VS 2012. I am getting following error when including "Movies.h" in one of my class header files

c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winbase.h(2905): error C2733: 'GetProcessInformation' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed
1>          c:\program files\quicktime sdk\cincludes\processes.h(430) : see declaration of 'GetProcessInformation'

I need to know why am I getting these errors and how to fix them.

Thanks
Nisar

Comment: please find some information on https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/visual-studio-2012

Comment: The problem was solved by setting Platform Toolset property of the Project to VS 2010. VS 2010 should be installed with SP1